# Non-uniformly rotating reference frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames

I have stumbled upon the concept of Euler Force in Wikipedia and it is stated that this happens in a "Non-Uniformly rotating reference frame".

What is it? It is just a synonym of non-stationary rotating reference frame (i.e. a reference frame where the a different from zero angular acceleration?)

Answer (score 2):

> It is just a synonym of non-stationary rotating reference frame (i.e. a reference frame where the a different from zero angular acceleration?)

I would say every rotating reference frame is "non-stationary"; since that would just mean moving.  For that reason, I would say your definition isn't really correct, since even a rotating reference frame with uniform angular velocity would be "non-stationary".

That said, your example seems to be right on.  A "non-uniformly rotating reference frame" is a rotating reference frame where the angular velocity is not constant in time.  That's the same as saying a reference frame where the angular acceleration is non-zero, which is the example you give.